# AddressSanitizer StackOverflow Error in LeetCode #1768 - Merged String Alternately

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, address-sanitizer

I'm currently trying LeetCode's [Merge Strings Alternately](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-strings-alternately/) problem. The description of this problem is given below:

> You are given two strings word1 and word2. Merge the strings by adding letters in alternating order, starting with word1. If a string is longer than the other, append the additional letters onto the end of the merged string.
>
> Return the merged string.

And one of the test case is this:

> ```cpp
> word1 = "rlvrpyrhcxbceffrgiy";
> word2 = "ktqi";
> ```

When I try this test case on my computer (I'm using CLion 2022.3.3), it works fine, but when I try to run my solution and test this case on LeetCode, it gets a Runtime Error.

Here is my solution:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string mergeAlternately(string word1, string word2) {
        
        string merged;
        char *p1,*p2;

        string longstring;
        
        if(word1.length() >= word2.length()){
            longstring = word1;
        }
        else{
            longstring = word2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < longstring.length(); i++) {
            p1 = &word1[i];
            p2 = &word2[i];
        
            if(*p1 != '\0' && *p2 != '\0'){
                merged += *p1;
                merged += *p2;
            }
            else if(*p1 != '\0' && *p2 == '\0'){
                merged += *p1;
            }
            else if(*p1 == '\0' && *p2 != '\0'){
                merged += *p2;
            }
        }
    
        return merged;

    }
};
```

And this is the error which I'm getting on LeetCode:

```
=================================================================
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fa4c5900390 at pc 0x559334397d01 bp 0x7ffebc3d6450 sp 0x7ffebc3d6448
READ of size 1 at 0x7fa4c5900390 thread T0
    #3 0x7fa4c7591d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
    #4 0x7fa4c7591e3f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
Address 0x7fa4c5900390 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 144 in frame
  This frame has 3 object(s):
    [32, 33) 'ref.tmp'
    [48, 80) 'agg.tmp'
    [112, 144) 'agg.tmp8' <== Memory access at offset 144 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x7fa4c5900100: f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5
  0x7fa4c5900180: f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5
  0x7fa4c5900200: f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5
  0x7fa4c5900280: f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5 f5
  0x7fa4c5900300: f1 f1 f1 f1 01 f2 00 00 00 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00
=>0x7fa4c5900380: 00 00[f3]f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fa4c5900400: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fa4c5900480: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fa4c5900500: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fa4c5900580: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x7fa4c5900600: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==22==ABORTING
```

Please explain why this is occurring.

Comment: Did you ask this question on the LeetCode forums?  If so, please link to that question so we can read the discussion there.  If not, why not?

Comment: You should post your entire code.  [It does not work here](https://godbolt.org/z/o18T9a9nM).  Why are you messing around with null-terminators?  Each string has a `size()` function, so you should use that to determine if you are the end of the string (or use iterators).

Comment: Recommendation: Run this again on your PC with debugging information preserved (`-g` on GCC and GCC-like tool chains) and you'll get a MUCH more descriptive sanitizer diagnostic telling you exactly what happened and exactly where. That usually just leaves figuring out how to fix it up to you.

Comment: Unrelated: Explain to [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) why `char *p1,*p2;` are pointers. Don't shy away from pointers, but don't use them to add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: More related: Discuss with your rubber duck what happens when `i` is greater than the length of the shorter string.

Comment: Your question title says stack overflow, but the error is stack buffer overflow. Those are very different things.

Comment: You are using pointers, but you would probably be far better off if you used different types of pointers, and more strategically.  You could have had `std::string* longer, *shorter;` and set those pointers to point to the longer string and shorter string, respectively.  Second, what if the longer string is 100000 characters, and the shorter string is 2 characters?  You loop on the longer length instead of the shorter length -- this is a time waster, as you will be doing unnecessary comparisons when the short string runs out.  Using these suggestions, the null-termination stuff goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings are different lengths, then you'll run right off the end of one of them, because you're always using the value `i` to get a pointer into each string, where `i` iterates over the longest string.

You might hit the NULL terminator in one string, but if you keep looping, you'll jump to the next byte in memory and enter the realm of undefined behavior.

```
for (int i = 0; i < longstring.length(); i++) {
    p1 = &word1[i];
    p2 = &word2[i];

    // ...
}
```

You should really be iterating over the *shortest* of the two strings in one loop, and then have two more loops *after* that to copy the remaining characters.

It is cleaner to do this using iterators, completely avoiding pointers:

```
string merged;
merged.reserve(word1.size() + word2.size());

// Interleave characters
string::const_iterator p1 = word1.cbegin(), p2 = word2.cbegin();
while (p1 != word1.cend() && p2 != word2.cend()) {
    merged += *p1++;
    merged += *p2++;
}

// Append remaining characters
merged.append(p1, word1.cend());
merged.append(p2, word2.cend());
```